# How to make anchor links inside v-html work in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I need to create user guide pages using v-html, and inside the pages there should be anchor links. However, the following HTML does not work within v-html.

Example: I have the following the template:

```
<span v-html="html"/>
```

And html contains (among other data) the following anchor:

```
<a id='foobar'>
```

If I add:

```
<a href="#foobar">
```

'outside' the v-html, the anchor link does not work.

Comment: Hi, why did you deleted that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791012/should-vue-js-2-transitions-work-with-single-file-components-style-embedded-in?noredirect=1#comment131999191_74791012

Comment: For this question: do you **need** to use `v-html`?

Comment: @kissu I deleted the question because the problem was with the CSS which made it misleading. For this question, I need to show HTML stored in the database and make anchor links.

Comment: Transitions are totally related to CSS, especially in that case. An edit of the title would be enough tbh. Removing content is usually not recommended because it can be of use to somebody else or I can reference it to other askers.

Comment: I recommend that you rather receive a JSON object and craft the links thanks to it. `v-html` is messy and should not be used casually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  <div v-html="msg"></div>
  <div style="margin-top:2000px;"></div>

  <div id="foobar">
    Tet
  </div>
```

---

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: '<a href="#foobar">Footer</a>'
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/LYrMbzd

Comment: I want to have the id inside the v-html data.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. I just created a working demo below. Please have a look. I hope it will help you in finding the root cause of the issue you are facing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pageData: `<a href="#foobar">Scroll to Footer!</a><br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              ...<br>
              <div id="foobar">
                Footer
              </div>`
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="pageData"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have the id inside the v-html data.

Comment: Menas? What exatly you want?